# NServiceBus SqlServerTransport with .NET 6 Worker Service Issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, nservicebus

I am attempting to use NServiceBus 7.7.3 and its `SqlServerTransport` with a .NET 6 worker service. The `SqlServerTransport` is using the `NServiceBus.Transport.SqlServer` 6.3.3 and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` 4.1.0 libraries.

When NServiceBus released version 7.x, it posted a [note about a configuration change for SqlServerTransport](https://docs.particular.net/transports/upgrades/sqlserver-6to7) and a
[code sample on using NServiceBus with a .NET worker service](https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/generic-host/?version=core_7)  that I followed to create this code:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .UseNServiceBus(context =>
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("CRM");
        string connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:CrmDatabase");
        SqlServerTransport transport = new SqlServerTransport(connectionString);
        endpointConfiguration.UseTransport(transport);

        //code for routing, defining critical error actions, etc.

        return endpointConfiguration;
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
     services.AddHostedService<GALSync.InterAction.Processes.CrmListener.Worker>();
    })
    .UseSerilog()
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
}
```

On the statement
`SqlServerTransport transport = new SqlServerTransport(connectionString);` the instantiation `new SqlServerTransport` raises the error "SqlServerTransport does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments."

The statement
`endpointConfiguration.UseTransport(transport);` raises the error "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'NServiceBus.SqlServerTransport' to 'System.Type'"

I updated the `NServiceBus` and `NServiceBus.Transport.SqlServer` libraries to 8.0.0-beta.3 and 7.0.0-beta 2, respectively, thinking there may be a .NET 6 issue with NServiceBus. The library updates removed both errors, but upon running, the code raised the "Either the connection string or connection factory has to be specified in the SQL Server transport configuration" error. The SQL connection string was tested and does connect to the SQL server allowing all SQL functionality to run perfectly.

I reverted back to the current production libraries and tried an older code configuration, which is slated to be deprecated:

`endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>().ConnectionString(connectionString);`

Like the beta libraries, this did not have constructor errors and when running raised the connection string not specified error.

This may be a bug from using .NET 6 with NServiceBus, but I could also be missing something. Any assistance getting the NServiceBus `SqlServerTransport` working with a .NET 6 worker service would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The link to the sample is not complete, can you check and edit the post, please? I'm trying to reproduce your steps. (the hosting sample I found is using .NET Core 3.1 SDK so I'm not sure if that sample is valid for .NET Core 6.x)

Comment: Thanks @SeanFarmar. I corrected the link, which is based on .NET Core 3.1. I was hopeful that the `SQLServerTransport` would be fine with .NET 6 as [this post](https://discuss.particular.net/t/nservicebus-support-for-net-6-complete/2902) states that NServiceBus support for .NET 6 is complete and that other updates were made to adapt the `SQLServerTransport` for .NET 6. It's definitely possible that I may need to get NServiceBus support involved, but I wanted to first post this on SO should I be missing something obvious (I am new to NServiceBus).

Comment: NServiceBus libraries have independent versioning. The first link you provided about the configuration change - that is for SQL Transport version 7, which is not released. You are using SQL Transport version 6, which uses NServiceBus 7, which only has the .UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>() configuration method.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBoike that's where I was going astray. I thought the transport library versions were tied to the versions of NServiceBus. It all makes sense now. Very much appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got this exact scenario working on .Net 6.  I'm using the "to be deprecated" version of

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>();
transport.ConnectionString(connectionString);
```

...otherwise, we're pretty much the same.  I did look at the constructors for `SqlServerTransport` and indeed, there are only constructors that take two arguments.  Take a look and see if either of those work for you.  The main purpose of this answer was to confirm that it does indeed work with NET6

Comment: Thank you @NickDevore! Upon reading your confirmation that the "to be deprecated" version of the NServiceBus configuration worked with .NET 6, I re-examined my code and discovered that the unspecified connection string error was coming from a different endpoint. Commented it out, retested, and can confirm that this works. I suspect the beta libraries correct for the constructor issue, but will wait for new production versions before refactoring to the recommended NServiceBus configuration. I very much appreciate the nudge in the right direction!